# Bash scripting: log commands that produced errors?

Tags: bash, error-handling, error-logging

I'm working on best practice for my bash scripts. At the top of each file, I put the following so it exits if any command produces an error:

```
set -o errexit
```

The problem is it doesn't help with debugging. I'm looking for a way of logging what command failed (i.e. the command and arguments that were run), and what line the error occurred on, and in which file.

What's a good way of doing this? E.g by a small set of commands at the top of each bash script? Perhaps having a central file that is used for all scripts to log such errors? What might those commands be?

Also, is it a good idea putting that in every script that needs it? Or should a single file with it be `source`'d into every script that needs it? Or perhaps there's a different way?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top. This will display all the lines as they execute.

Comment: There's at least some question about whether `set -e` is really a best practice, because it might make you sloppy about handing error conditions yourself and it doesn't always work as expected.  [see here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options:

- Use at the top of your script.sh file: `#!/bin/bash -x`
- Use `set -x` option in script.sh
- Use -x from command line: `bash -x script.sh`